# How to save images automatically after setting up a path?

Tags: automation, save, dm-script

I want to save my images automatically, but I don't know how to set it in DM. My script is as follows:

```
Image img
img.GetFrontImage()
string name
if ( GetString( "Enter Name of Sample", "Hello!", name ))
    result( "\nThe Name Of Sample is "+name)
string path
if ( GetDirectoryDialog("select path","",path) )
    result("\nSelected path is:"+path)

While( img.ImageIsValid() )
{
    For( number i=i; i<1000000;i++ )
    {
        img.SetName(name+i)
        img.SaveImage(name+i)
        img := FindNextImage(img)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide your code as plain text, so other users can copy and test it. Don't post a picture of your code, if you want to get useful answers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "automatically"? You want to save it, the moment it is first displayed? Or you want to save all images every X minutes?  Or you want to save all of them, when the user does a certain UI action? (Menu etc.)  Please describe in more detail.

Comment: I get a lot of images, it's first displayed, then I want to save all of them. so I  should name them firstly, then set a path to store them, finally the script can save them automatically when I use the script.

Comment: @user1438038 thank you, I should provide my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the main thing you are missing is a line that creates a full pathname from the combination of the destination directory path and the name for each image.  So in addition to the changes suggested in the answer by BmyGuest, you should add a call to PathConcatenate, as follows:

```
number i = 1
While( img.ImageIsValid() )
{
    img.SetName(name+i)
    string filepath = path.PathConcatenate(name+i)
    img.SaveAsGatan(filepath)
    img := FindNextImage(img)
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you've written will not save anything, but most likely produce an error.

In the `For`-loop you 1000000x get the "next" image to save, but when you reach the end the "next" image is invalid.
Therefore, the next iteration will throw an error at `img.SetName`, because `img` is not a valid image at that moment.

What you want to do is something like the following:

```
number i = 1
While( img.ImageIsValid() )
{
    img.SetName(name+i)
    img.SaveAsGatan(name+i)
    img := FindNextImage(img)
    i++
}
```